# Getting NullPointerException when trying to generate test reports using ExtentReports

Tags: selenium

My code look like below

```
ExtentReports extentReports = ExtentReports.get(OpportunityTest.class);
extentReports.init("C:\\DSMB_QA\\DigtalSMB\\src\\test\\lib\\emailtest.html",true);
extentReports.startTest("First test");
```

Logs are

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.support.RegexMatcher.getNthMatch(RegexMatcher.java:30)
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.markup.Content.renewSystemInfo(Content.java:44)
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.markup.DocumentConfig.renewSystemInfo(DocumentConfig.java:158)
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.initialProc(ExtentReports.java:269)
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.init(ExtentReports.java:262)
at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.init(ExtentReports.java:240)
at salesforceTests.OpportunityTest.createOpportunityAsaDMUUser(OpportunityTest.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:691)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:883)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1208)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:758)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
```

Comment: Please check the updated code documentation for Extent Report.

Comment: I would recommend using version 2+. Its a huge improvement over versions 1 and as per the docs, this version will not be supported after 31 of September.